# How does the Axiom of Regularity apply to $A=\{1,2,3\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, foundations

I cannot understand the axiom of regularity. It says that any generic non-empty set $A$ contains an element $X$ such that $ X\cap A = \emptyset $. How can this be true? If, for example I have a set $A = \{1,2,3\}$, according to this axiom there must be an element inside of this set such that its intersection with $A$ is the empty set, but $1,2,3$ are part of $A$, how can the intersection be an empty set?

Comment: Just because $X\in Y$ doesn't mean $X\cap Y\not=\emptyset$. Consider $X=\{1\}$ and $Y=\{X, 2\}$ for example. In your case - and using the set-theoretic definition of the natural numbers - we have $1\cap A=\emptyset$ even though $1\in A$.

Comment: But shouldn't X and Y have an intersection? 1 is present in both sets

Comment: @TheSalameless No, $1$ is not an element of $Y$, because $1\ne 2$ and $1\ne X$.

Comment: But Y is defined as having 1 and 2 as its elements

Comment: @TheSalameless No. $Y$ is *defined* as being the set the elements of which are $X$ and $2$. And $X$ is not $1$.

Comment: {1} is not 1, now I understand, but going back to the original question, why is this axiom true?

Comment: Keep in mind that in usual (ZF-like) set theory, everything in the universe of discourse is a set.  So if you want to have a set $A =\{1,2,3\}$, then $1,2,3$ themselves must be sets.  What sets do you want them to be?  The usual definition would be something like $1 = \{\emptyset\}$, $2 = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$, $3 = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\} \}$.  In that case, the set $A$ does indeed have empty intersection with the set $1$.

Comment: @TheSalameless - It's an axiom, that's why it's true -- or at least, why it's a theorem of ZFC. As for why it *ought* to be true, that's not a mathematical question, but a philosophical one.

Comment: Why do you think $1\cap A$ is not empty? What element do you think belongs to both $1$ and $A$? I'm guessing you think $1\in1$. That is a possible point of view. However, if you want $1$ to be an element of $1$, then you should be using some alternative set theory which does not include the axiom of regularity. Because the axiom of regularity was intended to prevent such stuff as sets being elements of themselves.

Comment: It doesn’t “have” to be true (you can work in set theories where this statement is false, such as one with Aczel’s Anti-Foundation Axiom). As to why you may want it to be true: it essentially says that while it is “sets all the way down” (in the usual set theory, everything is a set), there is a “bottom” in any set.

Comment: So it should be true because no set is an element of itself? It seems to me that the idea of every element as a set makes sense only if you define natural numbers with sets

Comment: There are two orthogonal notions in play here. 1) "Everything is a set." 2) "Every set is well-founded." Both of these hold in ZFC by assumption, but neither is a thing that obviously needs to be true in a mathematical universe based on the idea of sets. Best to hear instead 1) "we assume every mathematical object is a set"  2) "we assume every set is well-founded". The latter is the content of the axiom of foundation. It does prevent situations like $x\in x,$ or $x\in y\in x\in y\ldots$. These situations aren't inconsistent, and can even be interesting, but it's productive to disallow them.

Comment: It it neither the case that “it should be true” nor is it the case that “it shouldn’t be true”, any more than the Axiom of Choice “should be” or “shouldn’t be” true. It’s about what rules you want to play by. What you say about the natural numbers is, so far as I can tell, nonsensical. In ZF, **everything** is a set, period. Not just the natural numbers.  They don’t have to be, but that is the most standard “rule” we play by, because it makes things simpler and achieves everything we need or want.

Comment: (And by "we assume" I just mean we restrict the mathematical objects we consider as to not include anything to the contrary. This is not a philosophical statement about what exists in some sweeping sense, just about what we're considering.)

Comment: So, if I got it right, the axiom of regularity says that every set cannot have itself as an element, otherwise 1 and A would have 1 in common, if this is true, then 1 cannot have itself as an element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, what *is* $1$ and what *is* $2$ and what *is* $3$?

The Axiom of Regularity talks about sets in the language of set theory. So it presupposes that *everything is a set*. But $1,2$ and $3$ are not part of the language, so you need to specify how you interpret these objects *as sets*.

The standard way is by the von Neumann ordinal assignments: $0=\varnothing$ and $n+1=n\cup\{n\}$.

So $1=\{0\}=\{\varnothing\}$ and $2=\{0,1\}=\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$, and $3=\{0,1,2\}=\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\},\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}\}$.

So $A=\{1,2,3\}$ is a particular set, and you can check now that $1\cap A=\varnothing$.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand. Before I didn't define 1 as a set so I didn't know how we could assume that this axiom is true

Answer (score 0):

" whenever I try to chase down a chain of members , it must stop at some finite stage. You can think of it in this way. We have a string of sets $x_1, x_2, x_3....$ where each is a member of the preceding one ; that is : $..... x_3\in x_2\in x_1$. This we shall call a descending membership chain. Then the axiom ( Axiom of Foundation/ Axiom of Regularity ) is this : ***any descending membership chain is finite*** "

in Crossley *et alii* , *What is mathematical logic? OUP, 1972* (Chapter 6 " Set Theory", pp. 62-63)

---

So the axiom is aimed at ruling out the possibility of having such a descending chain.

Comment: It's a bit odd that you ask a question about your own answer *after* you've posted it.

Comment: This is because I first addded an assertion to this answer , but , after that, doubted whether my assertion was correct... and it wasn't

Comment: In case you have some time to answer the question I asked, I'd be pleased to read you.